# Push value to to next view when dismissing the current view

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with a button that triggers a modal flip horizontal segue animation to another UITableViewController. On the "flipside" I have a simple done button that dismisses the view if pressed. When dismissing the view I want to set the "test" string in MainTableViewController depending on what value the "test" string has in FlipsideViewController. I can't get that connection working though. Posting my code below:

**MainTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property NSString *test;

@end
```

**MainTableViewController.m**

```
#import "MainTableViewController.h"

@interface MainTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainTableViewController

@synthesize test;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    NSLog(@"%@", test);

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{return 1;}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{return 10;}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;

}
```

**FlipsideTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "MainTableViewController.h"

@interface FlipsideTableViewController : UITableViewController

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

**FlipsideTableViewController.m**

```
#import "FlipsideTableViewController.h"

@interface FlipsideTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation FlipsideTableViewController

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender{

    NSString *test = @"Hello!";
    // Push the test string to MainTableViewController

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{return 1;}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{return 10;}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FlipsideCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **delegate** for backward passing of data

Refer [simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/) link.

Also refer [basic-delegate-example](http://coderchrismills.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/basic-delegate-example/) link too.